# Select two table and get information

Tags: mysql

Im getting an error when I try to make this function:

```
 function get_score_by_id($server_id){
 $server_id = sanitize($server_id); 
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT votes.COUNT(votes.*) as number_of_votes ,
 SUM(graphic.online) / (SUM(graphic.offline) + SUM(graphic.online))*100 as uptime,
 graphic.MAX(graphic.Players) as maxp
 FROM votes,graphic WHERE server_id = '$server_id'");
 $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
 return (0.60 * $data['number_of_votes'])
  + (0.25 * $data['uptime']) 
  + (0.15 * $data['maxp']);
}
```

The error:

```
  Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 189
```

Comment: What is the set of errors not returned from the query?

Comment: (but the errors in the 2nd word)

Comment: Im trying to know if my query is right

Comment: you wont get help till we know what the issue is... i see code.. and it doesn't look broken to me from a preliminary view..

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the error now.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php... you need mysql_fetch_assoc to be in a while loop... not a variable equal to it.

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}` from the manual's example...

Comment: The error is on the query. I can do the mysql_fetch_assoc without a loop, because I have done it before and it works fine. But in thie function Im getting the error on the query.

Comment: well yea... `votes.COUNT(votes.*)` is incorrect. should just be `COUNT(votes.*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try fixing the COUNT.. change `votes.COUNT()` to just `COUNT()` -- and `graphic.MAX()` to just `MAX()`

```
SELECT COUNT(v.id) AS number_of_votes ,
       SUM(g.online) / (SUM(g.offline) + SUM(g.online))*100 AS uptime,
       MAX(g.Players) AS maxp
FROM votes v,graphic g
WHERE v.server_id = '$server_id'
```

Comment: Im keeping having the same error ):

Comment: @user3908253 where is server_id stored? votes? graphic?

Comment: well thats the problem.. change it to votes.server_id -- basically it will return an error saying that column server_id is ambiguous because it could be either one and it doesn't know which to choose from

Comment: I have changed and Its returning the same error ):

Comment: ok try just doing a `SELECT * FROM votes where server_id = '$server_id'`

Comment: Ok. If I do it, it works fine.

Comment: But, I want the other query working fine..

Comment: ok so try it again and this time change the COUNT to COUNT(votes.id).. i think COUNT(votes.*) is invalid code

Comment: @user3908253 sure thing.. look into the different aggregate functions and how they work. glad i could help :)

Comment: ok,Im going to study that, thanks!